# Trigger a button click with JavaScript when Enter key is pressed

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger a button click when the Enter button is pressed in my page. I know how to do it if it's in a form. Like this

```
<form>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="Some text.." value="">
    <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
    }
});
</script>
```

But how to trigger the button even when the Enter is pressed irrespective of where the focus is in the input element or not. just pressing the Enter button will trigger the button in the page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add your event listener to the document instead of the input

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank for describing that, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document`

When use `input.addEventListener` then it will listen event from input only and when use `document.addEventListener` then it will listen from the entire page

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="Some text.." value="">
    <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can bind the keyup event on window or document

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("oops!")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the event listener to that input element, bind the listener globally like this 
document.addEventListener("keyup", your_function_here);